# Throwing out food with "questionable" hechsher - bal tashchis?

Tags: halacha, food, kashrut-kosher, bal-tashchit-waste

If one receive cooked food from a person that perhaps used ingrediants from a hechsher that one normally wouldn't eat is it bal tashchis to throw out the food?

With packaged, store-bought food it would be easier to simply give it away to a neighbor or friend. However normally home-made food is harder to give away to others so, consider in this case that that option is not available.

If it is bal tashchis, then what should the person do? Simply let it sit in their fridge until it's no longer edible?

Comment: How is letting it rot any better? And if it is better, why keep it in the fridge, where it will take longer?

Comment: There is a machlokes if one has food which is kosher after batel bshisim if one doesn't feel comfortable eating it,can he throw it out or not,I believe the Pri Toar allows one to throw it out will check it out,but not sure if this case is comparable.

Comment: @SethJ, we see sometimes that it's better not to do something manually even though you're letting it happen automatically. (I have no idea whether that would apply here.)

Comment: @msh210, right, but here the issue is _wasting_ it, as in _not consuming_ it.

Comment: @sam They don't believe in the principle of Bittul? Sounds more like Kefira than a Chumrah.

Comment: @doubleaa The Pri Toar holds that,but many argue and hold one should eat it.

Answer (score 3):

http://olamot.net/shiur/%D7%91%D7%9C-%D7%AA%D7%A9%D7%97%D7%99%D7%AA has quite a lot of examples of bal tashchis. One that is similar to this question:

> גם בהשחתה משום חומרא אין איסור 'בל תשחית', וכמו שפסק רבי שמואל הלוי ואזנר [אב"ד זכרון מאיר, בני ברק] בשו"ת שבט הלוי [5] להתיר שפיכת משקאות חריפים בגלל שאינו סומך על מכירת חמץ בעין. ועי' במה שהוסיף בזה פרטים בספר עץ השדה [9].‏

I have provided a source which says one can pour out drinks where one has a chumra of not selling these for pesach even though bal tashchis is involved. This is very similar to question of a 'questionable' hechsher.

Comment: I would be greatly interested to know why my answer which also happens to be the only one, and contains a psak from the shevet halevi is not considered worthy of any points.

Comment: Don't push your luck around here ;).

Comment: Thanks Yehoshua. I suppose it was you that granted me the point!

Comment: shulem, the more people who actually learn something from your divrei Torah (ikkar), the more upvotes you'll tend to get (tafel). In this case, if you add a translation of the quotation you provided, a proper citation of who it came from, and a clear explanation of how it addresses the question at hand, this answer will be much more accessible and useful to readers, will thus result in greater spread of Torah, and will probably get you some more points.